# Is it possible to access a specific piece of a custom data type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, custom-data-type

I'm very new to haskell, and functional programming in general, I'm switching back and fourth between two different books on haskell, but I can't seem to find an answer to my question. Say I have a custom datatype like the one below

```
data Expr
  = Let String Expr Expr
  | Binary BinOp Expr Expr
  | Unary UnOp Expr
  | Literal Literal
  | Var String
```

and I have an instance of this data type that is in the form of the first constructor `Let String Expr Expr`, is it possible to access a specific piece of that `Expr`? For example if I wanted to access the `String` within that specific instance.

Comment: Sure: `let (Let name val body) = expr in …name…`, if you know that the `expr` is a `Let`. Or use any other form of pattern matching in functions or `case`

Comment: Often when you're asking a question about Haskell it will be useful to explicitly tell us the *type* of the function you're trying to write, if you can. Thinking about that is a good exercise, and will also help you write a more clear question.

Comment: @ChrisMartin I'm working on some homework, so I didn't want anybody to straight up solve the problem for me. But what I'm trying to do is create a function that takes an `Expr` datatype and returns the `xml` representation of that `Expr` as a String. Without you actually reading the homework handout that probably doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 4):

Pattern matching is your answer.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
myfunction :: Expr -> SomeReturnType
myfunction (Let str _ _) = doSomethingWith str   -- "str" here is your string
```

You'll want to handle the other cases as well though, so you don't cause a runtime error:

```
myfunction :: Expr -> SomeReturnType
myfunction (Let str _ _) = doSomethingElse str
myfunction (Binary _ _ _) = somethingEvenDifferent
myfunction (Unary _ _) = etc
--- etc...
```

the `_` just says to ignore the value at that position in the constructor.

---

Also, as @Bergi mentioned, there are many other places you can use pattern matching, like `let` or `case` statements, just always be sure to handle all the cases that your value could potentially be at that point in your program.

Comment: Oh wow I knew about using, if I remember correctly `wildcards`?, but that didn't really click with me for some reason.

Comment: In fact, such piecewise function definitions are syntactic sugar for `myfunction x = case x of (Let str _ _) = ...`.